# Possible bug in SOQL LIMIT clause

Tags: soql, query, bug

I've just encountered a weird behaviour of SOQL and I wonder if it's a bug or maybe some feature I do not understand: looks like the compiler lets you add an incorrect `LIMIT` clause - `LIMIT1` for example - and does not indicate any issues with that. It also doesn't limit the query actually.

Following queries: `SELECT Id FROM User LIMIT1`, `SELECT Id FROM User LIMIT43` both result in below:

[image: 1646 SOQL results]

Any ideas if there's a reason behind this behaviour?

---

**EDIT:** turns out the compiler ignores any word added to the end of the query, e.g. `SELECT Id FROM User FSAETGSRFESA`

[image: Random word SOQL 1646 results]

Comment: Have you tried the `LIMIT 1`? Give one space in between the `LIMIT` keyword and the `numberOfRows`. If you have run the query in developer console then first remove the result and try the **LIMT<Space>numberOfRows**. `SELECT Id FROM User LIMIT 1`

Comment: @TusharJadav I am aware of how it should look like :) I'm just wondering if that's a Salesforce bug or is there something else behind the behaviour

Comment: So basically any single word in the end of the query is ignored (apart from ones from official specs)?

Comment: @kurunve oh, you are actually right. That's still a bit surprising :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will be the [Alias Notation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_alias.htm) for objects. E.g.

```
SELECT count()
FROM Contact c, c.Account a
WHERE a.name = 'MyriadPubs'
```

In your case `LIMIT43` is actually an alias for `User`. So you will find this works as well:

```
Select LIMIT43.Id From User LIMIT43
```

Comment: I think the surprise on my part was that the object notation works on non-aggregate queries. The example query uses an aggregation, and we all know that you can't use field aliases in non-aggregated queries, so the natural assumption was that you couldn't use object aliases, either.